# Is SQLite strong enough to use as wordpress database?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, wordpress

i'm just curious. so i ask this particular question about SQLite. I haven't use this type of database extensively. but care to explain what is the basic different between SQLite and Mysql ?

The reason behind all of this is i just want to know whether it possible to use it to store wordpress data and act as a database ?

Comment: See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/09/12/lets-make-wordpress-officially-support-sqlite/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQLite is a file database. There is no running process or anything, it's literally just a regular file on your disk. MySQL is a full fledged database server, something that has to be run independently. SQLite is best suited for when applications need a small database to store settings or data.

You *could* do it with SQLite, but SQLite isn't really meant to be used concurrently (ie, by multiple users accessing it at once). So unless it's some dinky internal site that will only be accessed by a couple people, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: yes, it will be an internal site that access by small of people via intranet. it;s close environment without internet access

Comment: If you are going to have low number of users, SQLite will work just fine. Of course, low can be/is a relative term.

Comment: MAx 3 people on the same time, is low enough ?

Comment: Especially since it's mostly writes, that will work just fine.

Comment: Digging this up from the grave in order to add some "context about current times". The best use for Sqlite today is mainly local development where you don't want the overhead and workflow slowdown of running a full fledged database.

Comment: The latest SQLite is much better at multiple request handling

Comment: 2016: You need only one user to access the WordPress DB. The same user - your WP php app accesses it several times per page request. It writes to the DB only when one is writing a blog. The concurrent write problem is not likely to come up unless you are attempting to run wordpress as SaaS. Have I got anything wrong?

Comment: @LordLoh. Wordpress actually does write to the database even when the wpadmin user isn't logged in. Linkbacks, comments, adding accounts, various plugins, there are lots of different ways that the wordpress database may be utilized without the wpadmin.

Comment: [This blogger](https://darryldias.me/12/my-experience-with-wordpress-sqlite/) says that at 200-300 visitors (presumably a day?), SQLite was too slow on a 512MB droplet.

Answer (score 8):

[Currently, the only database supported by WordPress Version 2.9 is MySQL version 4.1.2 or greater.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

Comment: wow really? darn, so is it impossible from the beginning ?

Comment: Of course, almost every software should be specifically written to support any given DB.

Comment: @wRAR I'm not sure if that was sarcasm, but the point isn't that it should support "any given DB", but that it should come "batteries included"; it's already running on a webserver, why does it need yet another backend server to connect to? Can't it manage its own data?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you can use [WordPress with SQLite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdo-for-wordpress/). If you don’t have much traffic it is an option.

Comment: It should work for large traffic too. Just not if huge number of users, blogging at once. or commenting.

Comment: Unfortunately that plugin is dead in the meantime, this seems to be the plugin nowadays https://wordpress.org/plugins/performance-lab/

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is an in-process or desktop class database.  MySQL is a server class database.  I'm a little notorious here for promoting server-class engines over desktop or in-process -class engines for web sites, because no matter how well you do at your in-process database engine you are going to have concurrency problems when a whole bunch of people try to access your site at the same time.

However, I think in this case you might do just fine with SQLite, as long as you are very careful about what plug-ins you install.  The reason is that you're likely only going to have one person updating your wordpress blog, and probably in-frequently at that.  So as long as you're careful about using plug-ins that don't get to write to the database for every visitor, sqlite should do fine.

Comment: so, if there only one person who got access to write data into sqlite, then it would be oke. even though there some people reading the data via front-end ?

Comment: That's right.  Just be wary of plugins that do things like log referrer visits to the DB. Comments are another big one.  But as long as your site stays small and you avoid too much writing, you'll be okay.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivially easy to install a copy of MySQL and a webserver onto any machine, so while you *could* use SQLite, it would be a lot more difficult than simply grabbing a copy of MySql and installing it.

WordPress does not support anything but MySQL out-of-the-box, but it is possible for a database-plugin to replace that support with just about anything, if it really wanted to.

If you want to test this locally or something, just grab a copy of XAMPP and install WordPress on that. Easy.